# Haskell State monad explanation

Tags: haskell

I'm having this snippet, could you explain me what is does, especially >>= ?

```
instance Monad (State s) where
    return a = State $ \s -> (a, s)
    State st >>= f = State $ \s ->
        let (a, s') = st s
        in  runState (f a) s'
```

Eventually could you write it in a more clear form?
Thanks

Comment: `>>=` is the heart of a *monad*, so your question sort of reduces to *"what are monads?"*. Since the scope of that question is a bit big, I suggest you read an introduction such as [LYAH's monad chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads).

Comment: @gspr It's about a specific monad though. That seems to me like saying that asking how `concatMap` works is asking how monads work because `concatMap = flip (>>=)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code *defines* what `>>=` is supposed to do.

```
State func1 >>= f    =
  State $ ...stuff...
```

The `State` constructor has to be followed by a function that takes the current state and returns a new state and a result. So `...stuff...` must be such a function, and `func1` must also be such.

```
State $ \ state1 -> ...
```

OK, so, we want to "run" `func1` by giving it some state:

```
let (resultA, state2) = func1 state1
```

Next, we want to call `f` to get the next monadic action to do:

```
State func2 = f resultA
```

and now we "run" that, feeding it `state2` rather than `state1`:

```
in func2 state2
```

The example code above uses `runState`, but I thought I'd spell it out explicitly for clarity.

```
State func1 >>= f   =
  State $ state1 ->
    let (resultA, state2) = func1 state1
        State func2 = f resultA
    in  func2 state2
```

Answer (score 5):

If you squint, you can see that `State` really is a wrapper for functionality related to functions of type `(a,s)->(b,s)`, only curried: `a -> s -> (b,s)`.

Chaining functions of type `(a,s)->(b,s)` is really easy - plain composition. That way they can pass both "state" (`s`) and computation "results" (`a` to produce `b`) along the invocation chain. Of course, it becomes obvious that the distinction between the "state" and "results" is arbitrary. But if you are dealing with the curried version, it becomes a little more complicated, and that's taken care of by `>>=`.

But what is `Monad` for, if we can "chain really easily" the functions of type before currying? The `Monad` is there to take care of *boilerplate* related to state propagation even when the function doesn't depend on it - because most of functions don't. They start depending on state and changing the state (well, they actually become stateful), when they access the second projection of the tuple using `get` and `put`. Without `State` monad that would look like so:

```
get :: (a,s) -> (s,s)
get (_,s) = (s,s)
put :: (s,s) -> ((),s)
put (s,_) = ((),s)
```

By currying `(a,s)->(b,s)`, we get a hygienic stateful computation, separating concerns for dependency on `a` and `s`: we get rid of explicit dependency on `s`, unless specifically called out by the use of `get` and `put`. It's important to keep in mind their existence - otherwise it is not entirely obvious what's the fuss with passing `s` around:

```
get   = State $ \s -> (s,s)
put s = State $ \_ -> ((),s)
```

Now, back to `>>=`. What this function does, is combines `s->(a,s)` and `a->s->(b,s)` to obtain `s->(b,s)` - which now can be used to combine with `>>=` some more. If we didn't have the `State` constructor wrapper, the binding would look like:

```
as >>= f = \s -> (uncurry f) $ as s
```

That is, given state, feed into `as` to produce `(a,s)`, which are fed into `f` (uncurried to get `(a,s)->(b,s)` again) to produce `(b,s)`. But since we have the `State` wrapper, it becomes a little less obvious:

```
(State as) >>= f = State $ \s -> let (a,s') = as s --mean to call f (a,s'), but
                                     (State g) = f a --need to remove the wrapper
                                 in g s'             --to pass s' to (s->(b,s))
```

The unwrapping in your example is done using `runState`.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine a stateful function:

```
type StatefulFunction s a b = s -> a -> (b, s)
```

Let's create two such functions:

```
a :: StatefulFunction Int Int Int
a s x = (x + s, s)

b :: StatefulFunction Int Int Int
b s x = (x + s, s+1)
```

Those functions can change the behaviour based on the explicit state parameter. However, chaining them is tedious:

```
let startState = 0

let aParam = 42
let (aResult, newState) = a startState x

let bParam = 99
let (bResult, newState') = b newState y
```

`State` monad makes this chaining easier, and what I wrote above is precisely what `>>=` is doing for it:

```
a :: Int -> State Int Int
a x = fmap (+x) get

b :: Int -> State Int Int
b x = do 
    s <- get
    put $ s + 1
    return $ s + x

foo :: State Int Int
foo = (a aParam) >>= (b bParam)
```